# How to display PHP / SQL errors in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla

Try as I might, I can't get proper error messages in Joomla 3.1.5. No matter what I do, I get redirected to a nice "Error 0" page which doesn't tell me what happened where. I've tried setting error reporting to both maximum and developer in the admin console, and turning on developer mode. Is there any way to get proper error messages instead of friendly error messages to display in Joomla 3.1.5?

Comment: have you checked the error log via FTP?

Comment: Yeah, not getting anything :/ Normal PHP errors do appear there (if I cause a parse error, for instance) but a standard Joomla error (for instance, trying to get to a view which doesn't exist, or a SQL error) just gets wrapped up in a stupid "Error 0" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -- calling restore_exception_handler() gets rid of the poxy Joomla page and lets me read the text of the error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not seeing the errors it's likely that you have an extension installed that is calling `set_exception_handler()`, while I don't have an STS 3.1 version anywhere to test the 3.2's we do have don't have any issues with reporting errors. (And as far back as I can remember, I don't believe Joomla core calls `set_exception_handler()`.

We write Joomla extensions for clients as our primary business and I can tell you that the error reporting works. We have found in the past that some more dodgy extensions install their own exception handlers to hide issues in their code which is why we always develop and test on clear default Joomla installations.

#### Updated

Just saw your answer…

If that work's it means something is definitely calling `set_exception_handler()` <strike>which I don't believe is Joomla, I don't have have STS 3.1 installation but my current 1.5, 2.5 and 3.2's do not call `set_exception_handler()` in the Joomla core</strike>.

Comment: I think it's a core file -- found it in /libraries/cms.php:
   32  // Register a handler for uncaught exceptions that shows a pretty error page when possible
   33: set_exception_handler(array('JErrorPage', 'render'));

Comment: It does appear to still be there in 3.2... https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms.php

Comment: You're right and looking at the blame it's been there since 
2012-07-26… I wonder why my file scan didn't pick it up. :(

Comment: Usually Joomla's built-in exceptions are relatively helpful, I remember how they used to look... no idea why they aren't any more. There probably is an "is admin"/"is dev" check someplace which would show you a nicely printed but helpful error message. But I would rather just see the raw php exception for now, than just "Oops! Error 0!"

Comment: Somethings broken that's for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Few thoughts:

- Check in Joomla the PHP information - see the error reporting local
  value.
- Check for a local php.ini file
- Check if there is any ini_set code in your template...
- Try adding a code like below, in your template's index.php file.

code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I can see the ini values right before the point where the error happens and they're all as they should be. The problem's not that the errors aren't being raised, it's that they're being trapped by a generic Joomla error handler that I can't turn off.