# Localhost/Joomla displays "Error" with no more information

Tags: mysql, apache, joomla, localhost, virtualbox

When I try to login into the admin panel of Joomla in localhost/joomla, the browser only displays "Error" with no more information, not even a code number. Tried with Firefox and Chrome, all permissions allowed, apache2 and mysql started with php7.2 installed.

How can I solve this, or at least get information about the error?

The index.php file of apache2 works

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nPLY.png "displayed error"

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display PHP / SQL errors in Joomla 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341620/how-to-display-php-sql-errors-in-joomla-3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on a displaying an errors. For that:

1. Set display_errors=1 and error_reporting=E_ALL in php.ini
2. Set JConfig::$debug option = 1 in /configuration.php file

Also you may to see an error messages in error_log file.